# Blog entries and blog listing page are different content types?

Tags: 7, nodes

So I've noticed that Drupal sets the blog listing page as a different content type to the blog articles. This is a bit awkward because I want to set blocks that are specifically for the blog section.

In admin I can choose to restrict by content type: News Articles (the blog entries), or choose the pages on which the block displays displays: so list the page */blog* which is the Blog listings page.

How can I have harmony and set a block for blog listing and blog entry pages excluding the rest of the site?

Thank you

Comment: What you call the blog listing page is not a content type. It is just a page output from a module, but not all the pages output from a module are content types.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto) module to automatically set your blog URLs.  Set URLs for content of type blog to be blog/[node:title]; then, on the blocks configuration page, you can simply set the pages to be blog and blog/*, which will then show the block only on your blog pages and index but nothing else.